# clases objects in c#

Tags: c#, class, object

In the past I asked a question about the inheritance of three clases A B C

Take a look at [Clases and Objects in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465661/clases-and-objects-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1)

My new question, is it possible to do it if the class A Is an interface?

```
interface A {
...
}

class B: A {
...
}

class C: A {
...
}
```

Comment: Yes you can - it's called implementing an interface, but the class must implement all methods/properties on that interface or the class won't compile - all other generic stuff works the same

Comment: _Advice:_ read some good book on C#.

Comment: I recommend C# in Depth, by Jon Skeet

Comment: What do you mean _"is it possible"_? You just typed it, so it is possible. Do you mean whether it will compile, or give runtime errors? Try it.

Comment: Outside of the `unsafe` block, there is no "undefined behavior" in C#, so you can just *try* the code to see if it will compile and work as you expect. If it *doesn't* work like you expect, *then* you have a question to ask! :-)

Comment: -1: You clearly haven't even tried doing anything. Try downloading [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and __playing__

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference here. You still can't assign `C` object into `List<B>`.

```
var listA = new List<A>();
var listB = new List<B>();

foreach(A item in listA)
    listB.add(item);
```

Will throw exception if there is any `C` instance in `listA`.

But the other question solution will still work:

```
var listA = new List<A>();
var listB = new List<B>();

foreach(B item in listA.OfType<B>())
    listB.add(item);
```

Comment: I wanted to do it to build generic searchers and I wanted to know which was the best method to build them

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit from an `Interface`, its not called inheritance, its rather called implementation. What interface is doing is to remind you that what methods you have to implement in your code.

You can add as many interfaces when making a class, but you are limited to inherit only from 1 class.